# Can I get an explanation on escaping shell variables?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a C program I am integrating into a shell script.
There is a line that gets the time of birth for $HOME
using `system("stat $HOME | awk 'FNR == 8 {print}' | awk '{print $2}'");`
and it works great in C.
when I echo that line to bash with:

```
echo system(\"stat $HOME | awk 'FNR == 8 {print}' | awk '{print $2}'\");>> file.c
```

the second awk pipe doesn't happen.
so instead of getting: 2021-04-11

I get:
Birth: 2021-04-11 18:28:25.373220337 -0400

I don't understand the issue here.
I checked the resulting C code, and its missing `$2`
which is why the 2nd awk function fails. ok, so I escaped the with `\$2`
but I don't understand why I needed to. I didn't escape the other shell variable `$HOME`
and that works fine.

Comment: Presumably it "works fine" when you don't escape `$HOME` because you're executing the resulting program in the same environment that you're generating it in - so it doesn't matter whether `$HOME` is expanded by the current shell or by the shell invoked by the `system` call. FYI you can probably save a lot of headaches by using a [quoted here-doc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47436574/4440445) to construct your code, rather than an `echo` command.

Answer (score 3):

All `$` are interpreted as a variable by the shell (bash) inside `"`.
They need to be escaped.

Additionally, the `(` are interpreted by the shell, which needs a complete quoting of the string.

```
echo "system(\"stat \$HOME | awk 'FNR == 8 {print}' | awk '{print \$2}'\")" >> file.c
```

Besides this, you will get a problem as soon as `$HOME` has a space inside.

Reminder: There are better ways in bash and in C to get the needed information.

e.g. for bash:

```
date -d "$( stat -c %w "$HOME" )" +%F
```